# Need to displayed notification(v-alert notification) which will be reflecting on all page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is scenario where there is right drawer in which grade dropdown with list grade1, grade2, grade3 etc is been displayed and on all pages I need v-alert notification strip to display total count of student. So, for example from right drawer if I select grade3 then on v-alert strip total student of grade 3 will be displayed. If I change the dropdown value in right drawer to grade1 then total number of student for grade 1 will be reflected on v-alert on all pages.

NOTE - v-alert strip should be displayed on all pages just like navbar.

How can I achieve this?

Should I use stores for this?

Comment: As you are working with SPA, I am assuming that right drawer and v-alert should be in the master page (Entry page) and other components/pages loads dynamically inside the master page. In that case you can update the v-alert data dynamically from a single component itself on drawer value change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the component structure you have but I am demoing based on the assumption that you have both `drawer` and `v-alert` in a master page (parent page) and other routes are loading inside it. If my understanding is correct. You can give a try to this **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'Grade 1', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', count: 5 },
        { title: 'Grade 2', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', count: 10 },
        { title: 'Grade 3', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', count: 15 },
      ],
    }
  },
  template: `<v-navigation-drawer permanent>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-list dense nav>
                <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link @click="getStudentCount(item.title)">
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>`,
  methods: {
    getStudentCount(title) {
      this.$emit('student-count', this.items.find(obj => obj.title === title).count)
    }
  }          
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      right: null,
      studentCount: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getStudentCount(e) {
        this.studentCount = e
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card height="400" width="256" class="mx-auto">
      <v-alert border="left" color="indigo" dark>
        Count : {{ studentCount }}
      </v-alert>
      <child @student-count="getStudentCount"></child>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Jindal Thanks for you input but I have partially solve the issue yesterday but again stuck at a point where there is one file called as NavBar.vue. So, that file is loaded only once in the starting of project. In NavBar.vue file v-alert is present. I have stored grades in localStorage and from NavBar.vue file I am displaying that v-alert all over the project.Now I am storing changed grade in localStorage.On grade change value gets store in locaStorage and then displayed on v-alert but the issue is NavBar.vue file loads only once on page load.

Comment: So, on page load value is getting displayed but when I change the grade, in localStorage value is store but in v-alert localStorage value is not getting displayed because NavBar.vue file just load at once on page laod

Comment: @kiran Can you please tell me the component structure of both the pages ? Both navbar and drawer components are siblings ? or they are having parent-child relationship ? I am assuming drawer component also load once while loading the application only like navbar. Is that correct ?

Comment: In NavBar.vue drawer componenet is imported . import RightDrawer from './RightDrawer.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    RightDrawer
  },
  name: 'NavBar',
  data () {
  }

Comment: and in Drawer.vue file grade dropdown is present. In NavBar.vue file v-alert is there. I have used STORES to store gradeID which will be access through out the project. So, I take gradeID from STORES call an API receive required data then store that data in localStorage.Then on page load data on v-alert is correct but when I change grade that time in locaStorage value is getting updated but in v-alert it is not getting upated

Comment: @kiran - I got it now, drawer component is a child component of NavBar. Now you can simply achieve your requirement by emitting the value from your child (drawer component) on dropdown change to parent (NavBar component) and update the v-alert message. No need to use localStorage.

Comment: But NavBar render only once. Then how will I be able to update on every change of drop down.

Comment: @kiran - As dropdown is a child of navbar. It will update by emitting an event. I updated my answer with the code snippet. You can have a look. It is working fine as per your requirement without localStorage.

Comment: I have also added my code. Can you please once look into it might you will get an idea what I was trying to say. I have edited some part of code as it was very lengthy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251005/discussion-between-rohit-jindal-and-kiran).